# Save listview item

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement a listview and what I want exactly is:

The app launches, **1** item from ListView is being chosen and starts a webview. **This step is done**

But what I want is that **2.** time when I launch the app, it will start from that item and not show the list again. So it will continue always to start on that item I pressed first time.
I hope someone can show me a tutorial I can follow or some keyword I will try to see if I can do it.

**UPDATE --> Code*

```
    public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean firstrun = prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true);

    if (firstrun) {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
          editor.apply();

          // listening to single list item on click
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnkeltView.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("url", "https://google.dk");
              startActivity(i);

            }
          });           
        }
    // Save the state
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
        .commit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPreference works like a DB but in a small scale:[SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Android documentation: This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

So SharedPreferences shouldn't be getting wiped when a device reboots or force closes.

Comment: Try to put this Context.MODE_PRIVATE

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: You should save the data of the clicked item in the SharedPreference than starts the Activity, then you try in the second time to start the Activity from the sharedPreference

Comment: Okay, I think I done it. Thank you very much for explanation. I put starting intent outside the sharedPref. and its working now. Btw how I can go back to list again without uninstall the app? I mean its possible to do it through a button?

Comment: Sure you can do it through a button, and when you click in the list item you save it again in the sharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

you can store item in shared preferences in 1st time and during second time you can check if your shared Preference is not null then It launch the application with  item stored in it.

Comment: I just added code, But it doesnt really change sth. it starts still on first activity.

Comment: Did you add the intent  in on create of first activity like if(value from sharedPreference!=null){ Intent intent=new Intent(first.this,second.class);  startActivity(intent);}

Comment: yea i have this one :::     if(prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", false) == true)
        { 
         Intent intent=new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this,EnkeltView.class); 
         startActivity(intent);
        }